# jQuery Conflicting with MooTools

Tags: jquery, mootools

Is there anything I can do to make my jQuery work along with MooTools? I'm using [Videobox](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/) which uses MooTools and then I have some custom jQuery that I wrote. But my jQuery is not working, and the Videobox script is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

More here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your jquery code something like this:

```
(function($){

   // your code here

})(jQuery)
```

If you want to give out the control for `$` to other libs, you will have to call this:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

[more on the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict)

***The simplest solution would be to use `jQuery` keyword instead of `$`.***

Check out the post:

- [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 3):

Also, not sure if it's an option... but there's a videoBox (jqVideoBox) plugin that works with jquery (it's a port over from the mootools one).  Here is the link: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqVideoBox

Hope this helps.

Comment: Follow-up thought: Since both jQuery and MooTools are both frameworks, you're essentially using two-decent size libraries to achieve your above functionality.  I'm not sure if you're concerned about it, just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Use

jQuery.noConflict();

but you can't use $ as shortcut for jQuery not more easly.

When you want to, use it in a lambda function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery == $ 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this line after link to jquery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

and then use $j in place of $ for jquery and use $ for mootools.